# Настройка wifi ad-hoc на linux

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, wifi, nat

Здравствуйте!

Не могу расшарить интернет через *ad-hoc* соединение.

Есть стационарный компьютер (подключенный к сети интернет) и нетбук. На стационарном компьютере используется usb wifi-адаптер **Ralink**, нетбук использует встроенный wifi. Настроил ad-hoc соединение.

Соединение между машинами пингуется, **но выхода в интернет с ноутбука нет**.

### Стационарный компьютер:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. 

# lsmod
mt7601Usta            588572  1 
usbcore               195340  6 uhci_hcd,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,mt7601Usta

# ifconfig
lo ...
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:fc:92:83:b8  
      inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:fcff:fe92:83b8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:45580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:39559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:53146025 (50.6 MiB)  TX bytes:5103107 (4.8 MiB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e1:b0:71:49:91  
      inet addr:192.168.2.69  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2e1:b0ff:fe71:4991/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:45035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3451068 (3.2 MiB)  TX bytes:203488 (198.7 KiB)

# iwconfig ra0
ra0       Ralink STA  ESSID:"linux@"  Nickname:"MT7601STA"
      Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Cell: BE:2E:30:26:F3:B2   
      Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   
      RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level:-41 dBm  Noise level:-70 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

### Нетбук:

```
# lspci
02:00.0 Network controller:Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

# lsmod
ath9k                  84653  0 
ath9k_common           21530  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              380024  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    21707  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              421532  1 ath9k
cfg80211              350041  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211

# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:ca:ce:d1:c6  
      inet addr:192.168.2.96  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::208:caff:fece:d1c6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:103226 (100.8 KiB)  TX bytes:58895 (57.5 KiB)

# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"linux@"  
      Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: BE:2E:30:26:F3:B2   
      Tx-Power=14 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

### Скрипт для настройки интерфейса на стационарной машине:

```
ifconfig ra0 down
ifconfig ra0 192.168.2.69 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
iwconfig ra0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig ra0 channel 1
iwconfig ra0 Bit 54Mb/s
iwconfig ra0 essid 'linux@'
ifconfig ra0
iwconfig ra0
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Для нетбука похожий конфиг без форварда и маскарада, ну и, конечно, с другим ip и именем интерфейса.

Comment: Запускайте `tcpdump -n -i интерфейс` и смотрите пришли ли пакеты на сервер и ушли ли с него во внешний мир и с какими ip-адресами. так сходу проблем в настройках не видно

Comment: Я так понимаю, дело в том, что порт 53 недоступен, а как это исправить?  
*17:58:52.524798 IP 192.168.2.96.55370 > 192.168.2.69.53: 38138+ A? ya.ru. (23)
17:58:52.524824 IP 192.168.2.69 > 192.168.2.96: ICMP 192.168.2.69 udp port 53 unreachable, length 59*

Comment: Это DNS запрос с клиента на ваш сервак. У вас DNS-сервер не поднят. Или укажите на клиенте в настройках например гугловский DNS 8.8.8.8 или запустите на своем серваке named(bind) или другой DNS-сервер.

Comment: Нетворк менеджер вполне сностно настраивает адхок